# Shinyapp displays only on left-half of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

After a forced reboot yesterday evening, my shinyapp which was working fine for the last 10 months has started displaying only on the left-half of the browser window in edge.  The right-half is a blue screen as shown in the picture below.  The problem persists on chrome and IE also.

I have restarted R, RStudio and even rebooted the laptop multiple times.  I did try the following

`shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(width = '100%'))`

The plot and sidebar seem to be fixed.  When I reduce/increase the screen width only the blue part decreases/increases.

I would appreciate any suggestion to resolve this issue.  Perhaps there is a browser setting or js or css code that can override this setting.

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is only in one app. Other apps are not affected. It appears that recent update to edge interferes with my custom.css. Once I comment out that line, the blue screen disappears. Most of the customization in `custom.css` is not necessary now as I am using dashboard themes.

The second issue of only first menuitem not being active is due to image being included in the title bar of the `dashboardHeader()` with a `tags$li(a(href=...,img(src=...), class="dropdown"))`. It works fine with a `icon()` or by changing `img(...)` to `tags$img(...)`. Please note that the opensource consortium setting the rules on how the code should be processed did make a rule change recently. This affected my app.